# Logging flow in AWS S3 website to Cloudfront to WAF Security Automation Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-waf

I've set up a S3 static website with a Cloudfront distribution. In the S3 website bucket I added a folder for logs and enabled logging with logs/ prefix. In the Cloudfront distribution I turned on logging and mapped it to the bucket and logs/ prefix.

To add WAF I was following the guide below which launches a cloudformation stack. So far so good... until I reached the logging parameters. I'm really not clear if I need to set up a new bucket called "AWSLogs" or map it logs/ folder under the bucket for my website ? And do I need to change any of the previous log settings ?

Link to AWS Security Automation guide:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/aws-waf-security-automations/deployment.html#step1

From the above link:
+Application Access Log Bucket Name     +
If you select yes for the Activate Scanners and Probes Protection parameter, enter the name of the Amazon S3 bucket where you want to store access logs for your CloudFront distribution or Application Load Balancer. To deactivate this protection, ignore this parameter.

If you use an existing S3 bucket for this parameter, it must be located in the same AWS Region where you are deploying the AWS CloudFormation template. You cannot use the same S3 bucket for multiple deployments in the same AWS Region.

Note
Enable web access logging for your Amazon CloudFront web distribution or Application Load Balancer to send log files to this Amazon S3 bucket and remember to save logs in a folder named AWSLogs (log prefix AWSLogs/)

Then at Step 5 (see link) it outline the Cloudfront distribution log settings which seems to match what I've already set.

Answer (score 0):

Some AWS services that store logs in buckets always include `AWSLogs/` in the name of each object key, but CloudFront allows you to choose your own key prefix, which puts the logs in a folder with this name.

This setup -- for whatever reason -- appears to require that you specify `AWSLogs/` as the log prefix when configuring logging in CloudFront.

> Remember to save logs in a folder named AWSLogs (log prefix `AWSLogs/`).

If you chose something different as the log prefix (or no prefix at all) when you configured CloudFront logging, you'll need to go back and change it to this.

This is not the bucket name for your log bucket, which can be any valid bucket name.